# SQL not exists comparing backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm probably missing something really simple here but I'm wondering why this query does not work. I have a database and a backup of it, the current version with more rows that have been added since the backup. I just wanted to get the rows that don't exist in the backup and this looks like it should work but returns nothing. What am I missing and how does it return nothing?  When I remove the 'not' it returns as if there was no where clause. Seems like it should have the opposite effect.

```
select *
from db.dbo.table
where not exists (select * from db_backup.dbo.table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your query does is actually checking if there're **any record** in `db_backup.dbo.table`. So if there 0 records, it will return all rows from `db.dbo.table`, otherwise it'll return nothing. You have to use some kind of key, like this:

```
select *
from db.dbo.table as t
where not exists (select * from db_backup.dbo.table as t2 where t2.id = t.id)
```

if your tables schema is similar, you can use except:

```
select * from db.dbo.table as t
except
select * from db_backup.dbo.table
```

Comment: @awhitehouse104 you can use except in this case